# If n is an odd pseudo prime number, then $M_n = 2^n-1$ is a larger one

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I came across this Theorem in "Elementary Number theorem" by David B. Burton :

"If n is an odd pseudo prime number, then $M_n = 2^n-1$ is a larger one."

I am not able to understand why this result holds only for odd pseudo prime number ?

There has been a [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76431/if-n-is-an-odd-pseudoprime-then-2n-1-is-also-odd-pseudoprime) on the proof earlier, but I can't find any discussion for the odd case.

The proof in the book goes as:

Because n is a composite number, we can write $ n = rs$, with $ 1 < r \leq  s < n$. Then $ 2^r -1 \mid 2^n-1 $, or equivalently $2^r - 1 \mid  M_n $ making $M_n $ composite. By hypothesis, $2^n \equiv 2 $(mod  n)  ; hence $2^n-2 = kn $ for some integer k. It follows that

$ 2^ {M_n-1} $ = $2^{2^n-2}$ = $2^{kn} $

This yields

$ 2^ {M_n-1} - 1 $  = $2^{kn} - 1 $

= $ 2^ {n-1} $ ($ 2^ {n(k-1)} $ + $ 2^ {n(k-2)} $ + ... + $ 2^ {n} $ + 1 )

=  $M_n$ ($ 2^ {n(k-1)} $ + $ 2^ {n(k-2)} $ + ... + $ 2^ {n} $ + 1 )

$\equiv 0$ ( mod $M_n$)

We see immediately that $2^{M_n} - 2 \equiv 0 (mod M_n) $, in light of which $M_n$ is pseudoprime.

Comment: "pseudoprimes": those numbers which are "pseudo"-prime wrt ***to which prime-test***? This is essential, and possibly you can then answer this yourself...

Comment: According to the book definition "A composite integer n is called pseudoprime whenever $n \mid 2^n -2$ ".

Comment: I'm currently reading the same book. I think there is an error: a pseudo-prime is a composite number n such that $n\mid 2^{n−1}−1$. If the book's definition were right, then $4$ would be a pseudo prime to the base $4$. Yet the smallest pseudo-prime to the base $4$ is $15$.

Answer (score 1):

If $n|2^n-2$, let $2^n-2=nm$.  Then we want to prove $M_n=2^n-1|2^{M_n}-2=2^{2^n-1}-2$.  But $2^{2^n-1}-2=2 \cdot2^{2^n-2}-2=2(2^{nm}-1)$.  $m$ is even, so let $m=2k$  Then $2^{2^n-1}-2=2(2^{2nk}-1)=2(2^{nk}+1)(2^{nk}-1)$ and we know $2^n-1|2^{nk-1}$ so $M_n|2^{M-n}-2$

Comment: I have edited the post to show the proof given in the book.